# Laravel Artisan: Returns 0 for Python output

Tags: php, python, laravel

I have written one python utility program which returns an array of the result. This utility takes an image path as an input, process that image and in return gives an json array of the result.
Now I want to show this output on my website which is using Laravel 5.7
So I created one artisan command which executes python script and gives me the result.
This command works well in terminal but when I execute this same command from my controller using **Artisan::call** method, it shows me "0" as the output in the web browser.
I tried **shell_exec()** too. But the result is the same.

**Here is my Artisan Command File**

```
$process = new Process('python3 my_python_script.py -i ' . $this->argument('path'));
$process->run();
$result = $process->getOutput();
return $result;
```

**Artisan Command**

```
php artisan image:upload image_path
```

Answer (score 0):

The call method of `Artisan` returns integer. It doesn't read from output or it is not your return value from handle method.

See:

```
/**
 * Run an Artisan console command by name.
 *
 * @param  string  $command
 * @param  array  $parameters
 * @param  \Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface|null  $outputBuffer
 * @return int
 */
public function call($command, array $parameters = [], $outputBuffer = null);
```

Maybe you should try `Artisan::output()` but I don't think that it is thread safe or something like that.